# Center text vertically with paragraph inserted tikzpicture

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to insert a little tree in the middle of a paragraph, I am using this:

```
\tikzstyle{op}=[shape=rectangle, rounded corners, draw=black, align=center, fill=blue!30]
Si A est l'arbre 
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node [op] {'+'}
child { node {B} } child { node {C} };
\end{tikzpicture}
, alors dérivee(A) est l'arbre
```

In the output, the paragraph text is aligned with the bottom of the tree picture:
[image: output of the previous code]

Is there a way to make it aligned to the center of the picture? Something like:
[image: desired result]

Comment: Use `\begin{tikzpicture}[local bounding box=bb,baseline=(bb.center)]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One typically wants to have the baseline of the `tikzpicture` at the baseline of a normal sized node sitting at the center of the `tikzpicture` since otherwise the space below and above is asymmetric. This prescription can be made a style.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{
op/.style = {shape=rectangle, rounded corners, draw=black, align=center,
fill=blue!30},base align tikzpicture/.style={execute at end picture={
\path (current bounding box.north) -- (current bounding box.south)
node[midway](Xphantom){\phantom{X}};},baseline={(Xphantom.base)}}
        }

\begin{document}
Si A est l'arbre
\begin{tikzpicture}[base align tikzpicture]
\node [op] {'+'}
child { node {B} } child { node {C} };
\end{tikzpicture}, alors d\'erivee(A) est l'arbre
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{
op/.style = {box/.style = {draw, rounded corners, fill=blue!30},
             level distance=9mm, sibling distance=9mm,
             baseline = (current bounding box.center)}
        }

\begin{document}
Si A est l'arbre
\begin{tikzpicture}[op] 
\node [box] {'+'}
child { node {B} } child { node {C} };
\end{tikzpicture}
, alors dérivee(A) est l'arbre
\end{document}
```